# Drake - Rotation of objects appears to be locked even though I did

Tags: drake

[Image of "Floating" Boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK0IX.png)

I made a simple simulation using custom obj and SDF files for these boxes I made.  Hydroelastic contact is enabled (but the same behavior is also seen with point contacts). The boxes have mass and their inertia is a sphere perfectly at their center. I am adding the sdf to the scenario using `load_scenario` and `MakeHardwareStation`. I am not locking their rotation or position anywhere. When I run the simulation, why do the boxes "float"? Why do they not tip over and fall? I am not locking their rotation or position anywhere.

This is the bulk of my code:

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()

### Add Boxes
relative_path_to_gnd = 'Ground.sdf'
absolute_path_to_gnd = os.path.abspath(relative_path_to_gnd)

box_directives = f"""
directives:
- add_model:
    name: Ground
    file: file://{absolute_path_to_gnd}

- add_weld:
    parent: world
    child: Ground::Ground
"""
for i in range(NUM_BOXES):
    relative_path_to_box = 'Box_0_5_0_5_0_5.sdf'
    absolute_path_to_box = os.path.abspath(relative_path_to_box)

    box_pos_x = np.random.uniform(-1.5, 1.5, 1)
    box_pos_y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 1)
    box_pos_z = np.random.uniform(0, 5, 1)

    box_directives += f"""
- add_model: 
    name: Box_{i}
    file: file://{absolute_path_to_box}
    default_free_body_pose:
        Box_0_5_0_5_0_5:
            translation: [{box_pos_x[0]}, {box_pos_y[0]}, {box_pos_z[0]}]
            rotation: !Rpy {{ deg: [0, 0, 0] }}
"""

print(f"box_directives: {box_directives}")
    
scenario = load_scenario(data=box_directives)


### Hardware station setup
station = builder.AddSystem(MakeHardwareStation(
    scenario=scenario,
    meshcat=meshcat,
))
scene_graph = station.GetSubsystemByName("scene_graph")
plant = station.GetSubsystemByName("plant")

diagram = builder.Build()
simulator = Simulator(diagram)

####################################
### Running Simulation & Meshcat ###
####################################
simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1)
simulator.set_publish_every_time_step(True)
plt.show()

meshcat.StartRecording()
simulator.AdvanceTo(box_randomization_runtime)
meshcat.PublishRecording()
```

I also made this notebook with barebones code replicating the issue: https://deepnote.com/workspace/michael-zengs-workspace-61364779-69ef-470a-9f8e-02bf2b4f369c/project/05-Bin-Picking-Duplicate-472e49aa-3d46-46ad-af7a-54f4c4a4294a/notebook/falling_things_test-ba1ae56fa3ad4ca6b6f3a73652f3d3e0

It appears to me like the rotation of the boxes is locked somehow; when I add the box directives into the scenario at an angle, they remain at the same rotation:

[Image of "Floating" Boxes at a Different Rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsMJH.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! Inertia of the box (defined in the SDF file) was huge:

```
<inertia>
    <ixx>5208333333333336.0</ixx>
    <ixy>-0.9094947017729282</ixy>
    <ixz>-0.9094947017729282</ixz>
    <iyy>5208333333333336.0</iyy>
    <iyz>-0.9094947017729282</iyz>
    <izz>5208333333333336.0</izz>
</inertia>
```

which effectively locked the box's rotation. I just had to make the inertia a reasonable number (changed it to 0.5 * identity matrix, since the box is 0.5 x 0.5 x 0.5 m).

Comment: For the record, as an example to others, could you include the dimensions of your box and the bad inertia compared to the good inertia? Some concrete numbers might help future readers recognize some of their own problems.

Comment: Also... would the inertia visualization tool in meshcat have helped, if you had used it?

Comment: Just modified the answer to include the box dimensions and inertia.

Comment: As for the inertia visualization tool--I am still confused about this. I can't send an image here to illustrate (I'll send Russ the images on slack), but even with the massive inertia matrix, the inertia visualization in meshcat still appears as a small sphere at the box's center. When I changed the inertia to be 0.5*identity_matrix, the inertia spheres in meshcat actually appeared bigger. This perhaps contributed to the confusion.

Comment: Update on the inertia visualization--https://github1s.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/HEAD/visualization/inertia_visualizer.cc#L177-L178 suggests that the size of the ellipsoid in the visualization is only dependent on the mass value set in the SDF file. The inertia visualization appearing smaller for the humongous inertia matrix is probably due to rounding errors.

Comment: Drake also has a tool to rewrite URDF/SDF inertia tensors, based on geometry and mass in the input file. See https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.fix_inertia.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use SpatialInertia class:

from pydrake.multibody.tree import SpatialInertia

spatial_inertia = SpatialInertia.SolidBoxWithMass(
mass=1, lx=0.1, ly=0.2, lz=0.4)

mass = spatial_inertia.get_mass()

center_of_mass = spatial_inertia.get_com()

matrix6 = spatial_inertia.CopyToFullMatrix6()

print(f"mass = {mass}\n")

print(f"p_PScm = center of mass = {center_of_mass}\n")

print(f"I_SP = rotational inertia = \n{matrix6[:3, :3]}\n")